# serde_yaml::Value -> serde_json::Value, `null` keys

Tags: rust, serialization, serde, serde-json

I have big complex YAML file, which I successfully read into `serde_yaml::Value` and need to send to the user (from Axum handler) as JSON.

But somewhere deep inside that big YAML there are keys like `null`. And `serde_json::json!` panics with message "key must be a string".

I understand that this is valid case for YAML, but not valid for JSON.
But is there some workaround for that? I just need string keys like `"null"` in place of those nulls.

JavaScript and Go YAML parsers behaves exactly like this...

I wrote a big recursive function for that, which manually converts values, but maybe this is overkill. And also my function somehow breaks YAML merges (`<<`), don't know why yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply deserialize the yaml into a `serde_json::Value` instead, that way it's guaranteed to be serializable to json later:

```rust
fn main() {
    let yaml: serde_json::Value = serde_yaml::from_str(r#"null: "hello""#).unwrap();
    let json_str = serde_json::to_string(&yaml).unwrap();
    println!("{json_str}");
}
```

output:

```
{"null":"hello"}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b5008af8b515f98798bf1a1e47398921)

Comment: Wow, that is neat! But in that case a cannot do `apply_merge` https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/latest/serde_yaml/enum.Value.html#method.apply_merge there are such parts in my YAML as well ._.

Comment: But you hinted me other solution: after performing `apply_merge`, firstly convert `serde_yaml::Value` to string via `serde_yaml::to_string(&yaml)` and then convert it back to `serde_json::Value` via `serde_yaml::from_str(&yaml_str)` :) Don't like double conversion though, but is is better, than manual recursion, I guess...

Comment: `serde_json::to_value(&yaml)` might be more useful than `to_string` to you.

Comment: Nope :( `serde_json::to_value(&yaml)` chokes on `null` keys too